# vue css no animation on menu expand

Tags: css, vue.js, animation

Animation works on collapse, but not work on expanding.

I added css style for max-height, but animation only work on menu collapse.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>
      <button @click="isShow = !isShow">click -- {{ isShow }}</button>
    </p>
    <ul ref="menu" :class="{ menu: true, fold: !isShow }">
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item3</li>
      <li>item4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, reactive } from "vue";

const menu = ref("null");
const isShow = ref(true);
</script>

<style scoped>
.menu {
  max-height: 300px;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease;
}

.menu.fold {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}


</style>
```

https://codepen.io/wgf4242/pen/XWRKORW

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
  overflow: hidden;
```

to your **.menu** class, not to **.menu.fold**

The animation will start working, but keep in mind that expand animation will be faster than collapse animation because of the different sizes browsers use for calculation: 0 => 300px on expand and 72px => 0 on collapse. You can solve this problem by adding an additional wrapper for the menu and setting max-height to it's real size on click